# How do I send pipeline artifact by email in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm starting out with Azure DevOps and I trying to find a way to get the artifact I created in the pipeline and send it by email (as part of the pipeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature not exist in Azure DevOps and I don't recommend to send the artifacts by email because the artifacts size should be very big.

What you can do is to install [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.SendEmail) extension (or [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask)), there you can send email during your build pipeline but only a text, so just send the artifacts download link, when the user will get the email he will click the link and will download the artifacts.

You just need to configure the SMTP server and the Message that will contains the link:

[image]

In the "Message" field replace `{org}` with your organization name, `{project}` with the project name and `{name}` with the artifacts name you specified in  "Publish Artifacts" task (e.g. "drop").

Comment: Thanks @Shyki Abramczyk. This is about the solution I was thinking of but I thought maybe there is a better way. I couldn't figure out is how to get the URL of the download to the email. the download link is something like this: [link](https://dev.azure.com/$(project)/_apis/resources/Containers/**6417722**?itemPath=$(artifact name)%2F$(the file name) ). I just couldn't find what is the variable of the number in bold (which I assume is the container number).

Comment: Did you try my URL?

Comment: thats a container id